# Tag for fingerstyle bass?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

I just asked a couple of questions about fingerstyle bass technique and it wasn't clear which tags to use. There was [fingerstyle-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerstyle-guitar) and [finger-picking](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finger-picking), but it wasn't clear what the difference is between the two or whether they were appropriate for bass guitar. I'm not familiar enough with fingerstyle guitar to know whether it should share a tag with the bass. Likewise I'm not sure whether finger-picking is a distinct style or a synonym. Could our more knowledgeable guitarists and bassists help sort this out?

Comment: If you think it should be, we could create a distinct tag.  Otherwise I'd say just use `bass`.

Comment: @Matthew Just [tag:bass] might work well as it's the predominant style of playing anyway. Although part of my confusion was the meaning of the existing tags. One doesn't have a wiki or description, so it's not clear what it's for.

Comment: Based on my memory of previous discussion, they're meant to be specific.  So `x-guitar` won't include any kind of bass guitar.  I've also merged `finger-picking` into the other tag because it was only used in conjunction with it and seems synonymous enough.

Comment: @MatthewRead Thanks for clearing that up! I adjusted the tags on my question to match, created [tag:fingerstyle-bass]. When I get a chance I'll look at older bass posts and see if any should get the tag.